# Cookies page index

Tags: cookies

My homepage is a webportal. The visitors must choose a city and will be redirected to the correct site. But I want their choice to be remembered so they don't have to choose their city again.

I have no idea how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: You should try to expand this to talk a bit more about the stack you're using, how does the language switching already work, etc. At the moment, this is a very broad conceptual request - not a question about your specific problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to specify my problem? Why do you speak about language?